# A first line of a business email when you don't know the name nor gender of a person you write to (and time-agnostic too)

Tags: british-english, formality, business-language, email, greetings

"Greetings," and "hello there" are not businessy enough, are they?
"Dear Sir or Madam," sounds a bit too pompous.
"Good time of a day" sounds strange.
Are there any better ideas, especially for British English?

Comment: Hello does not seem to be formal enough. And Good Morning/Attention is not time agnostic. Are there any more interesting options?

Comment: "Dear Manager" (or whatever the job title is) is possible. There is the traditional "To whom it may concern".

Comment: There is a standing etiquette around greetings in letters. Yes, as we move to email we might dispense with such etiquette, but if you're looking to avoid informality, you can simply turn to it. On the other hand, I like the argument that email is meant to be utilitarian, direct, and minimal, and we need no greeting phrase. If you wish, you can soften the opening with some sincere small talk like "I hope you're doing well."